# TreeListControl в связке с каким элементом использовать

Tags: devexpress, wpf

Приветствую! Я хочу сделать в Visual Studio такое приложение, где бы слева постоянно находился TreeListControl (DevExpress). Другого привычного TreeView нет в DevExpress( вроде бы). А справа была область, которая бы изменялась( менялась страница или панель) при выборе какого либо узла (item) у treeview. И еще страница эта могла бы содержать какие-то контролы, и выполнялась какая-либо логика.
     Вот как интерфейс веб приложений по настройке сетевых девайсов.

Вот подскажите, в связи с этим , какие тут элементы управления надо использовать применительно к DevExpress( желательно).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто.

Во View положите в 0-ую колонку `Grid`'а `TreeListControl`, в 1-ую контрол, отображающий узел с подробностями.

В вашей VM надо прибиндить `TreeListControl.SelectedItem` на свойство (например) `CurrentItem`. А `DataContext` контрола из первой колонки View забиндьте на этот же `CurrentItem`.

Если ваши узлы разнотипные, вместо контрола в первой колонке нужен `ContentPresenter` + набор `DataTemplate`'ов.

Comment: Я ,наверное, это пойму все как Вы объяснили, но не сейчас..)  Grid-это будет у меня та область справа(большая), где у меня и контролы будут с различной логикой? Там же в зависимости от того какой я узел или подузел кликну(выберу), то и на Grid , что справа картинка меняться должна..(такя хочу)

Comment: @vlazarev: Не-не, `Grid` содержит как `TreeView` (в 0-ой колонке), так и область с контролами (в 1-ой колонке).

Comment: Все! представил как должно быть! А в Grid можно вообще что хочешь вкладывать . Спасибо!